# Postgres Exporter unable to parse my customized queries.yaml file

Tags: postgresql, prometheus, prometheus-postgres-exporter

I am helplessly trying to get my [postgres exporter](https://github.com/prometheus-community/postgres_exporter) running but in vain. After running my postgres container and then running my postgres exporter container as the following :

```
terminal1%docker network create --subnet=192.168.1.0/24 --gateway=192.168.1.1 prometheus-net

terminal1%docker run --network=prometheus-net -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password postgres

terminal2%docker run \
  --net=prometheus-net \
  -p 9187:9187 \
  -v /Users/johndoe/queries.yaml:/etc/postgres-exporter/queries.yaml \
  -e DATA_SOURCE_NAME="postgresql://postgres:password@192.168.1.2:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable" \
  quay.io/prometheuscommunity/postgres-exporter \
  --extend.query-path=/etc/postgres-exporter/queries.yaml

terminal3%cat /Users/johndoe/queries.yaml
custom_queries:
  - name: user_count
    help: "Total number of users"
    query: "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users"
    metrics:
      - user_count:
          usage: "GAUGE"
          description: "Total number of users"
```

So when I : `terminal3%curl http://localhost:9187/metrics` I get this error right here in terminal2 : `caller=postgres_exporter.go:674 level=error msg="Failed to reload user queries" path=/etc/postgres-exporter/queries.yaml err="yaml: unmarshal errors:\n  line 2: cannot unmarshal !!seq into main.UserQuery"`

I double checked whether the table users exists in the schema postgres and yes it does. Also there seems no problem with the connection between the exporter and postgres server. I just have no idea why my .yaml file cannot be parsed.

Comment: Your syntax seems to differ significantly from [expected one](https://github.com/prometheus-community/postgres_exporter/blob/e7f58a42e8040936d7e28f0a99c6823dba7ef6f7/queries.yaml).

Comment: @markalex Thank you. I fixed it. The queries.yaml provided in the source code is empty. Therefore I had no knowledge of how to format my queries.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the syntax of my queries.yaml. The right syntax should look like :

```
table_users_count:
  query: |
   SELECT
     COUNT(*) user_count
   FROM
     users
  metrics:
    - user_count:
        usage: "GAUGE"
        description: "Total number of users"
```